# Ubuntu apparently doesn't recognize wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 on an older Acer laptop. I'm running the live CD, and Ubuntu doesn't recognize the Broadcom 802.11g wireless adapter. Windows Vista connects no problem. I'm a newbie, and compiling the code provided by Broadcom for a new driver doesn't appeal. Any easier fixes available?

Comment: The solution depends entirely on your exact device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: lspci -nn | grep 0280  Edit your question to add the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Broadcom Adapter and had the same problem. Turned out that the driver just wasn't enabled by default. Take a look at the drivers section in the system settings. There should be a proprietary driver available. Just activate it and everything should work fine. If you install Ubuntu it might be required to activate it again (you'll need an internet connection to do that, i.e. LAN)